# Why does the container of this text so much wider than it should be?

Tags: html, css

I am building an effect for a website and I wanted to add a typewriter-like effect. The code looks like this.

```css
typed-out {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: initial;
  font-size: 4.6rem;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typing 1.5s steps(30, end) forwards;
}

.container-type {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.welcome {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: initial;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typing_2 1.5s steps(25, end) forwards, blinking 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

.container-type-welcome {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
    /*non: initial;*/
    border-right: .15em solid var(--sunshine);
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
    border-right: initial;
  }
  99% {
    border-right: .15em solid var(--sunshine);
  }
  100% {
    border-right: initial;
  }
}

@keyframes blinking {
  from {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  to {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}

@keyframes typing_2 {
  from {
    width: 0;
    border-right: .15em solid var(--sunshine);
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
    border-right: .15em solid var(--sunshine);
  }
  99% {
    /*border-right: .15em solid var(--sunshine);*/
  }
  100% {}
}

.welcome-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: initial;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typing 1.5s steps(25, end) forwards, blinking 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.text_main_1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: initial;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typing 1.5s steps(25, end) forwards, blinking 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

.text_main_2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: initial;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typing 1.5s steps(25, end) forwards, blinking 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.I-AM {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: initial;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typing .35s steps(5, end) forwards, blinking 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.text_main_3 {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: initial;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typing 1.5s steps(25, end) forwards, blinking 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 6.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-type">
  <p class="welcome-1" style="text-align: left;margin-left: 3vw;">I'm an aspiring developer!</p>
  <div class="container-type">
    <p class="I-AM" style="text-align: left;margin-left: 3vw;">I Am:</p>
    <div class="container-type">
      <p class="text_main_1" style="text-align: left;margin-left: 6vw;">A Full Stack Engineer</p>
      <div class="container-type">
        <p class="text_main_2" style="text-align: left;margin-left: 6vw;">A C++ and C# Programmer</p>
        <div class="container-type">
          <p class="text_main_3" style="text-align: left;margin-left: 6vw;">And some more!</p>
          <div class="container-type">
            <p class="welcome" style="text-align: left;margin-left: 3vw;">Finally, Welcome!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But unfortunately, the final effect messes up and the typing head goes too far. Here's a video to show the effect.[image: Video]
And yes I know it's an adobe preview! It's just a placeholder. Haha!

Comment: Please add your html and put everything into a runnable snippet so we can take a look.

Comment: @FabianSchöner Done! I have edited my post! This is the code and it all works besides the background!

Comment: What font are you using? It has to be a `monospace` type. Since every char has a different width, a monospace font family sets a same width for each char and thus enables the typewriter effect properly.

Comment: @Gil I like the font I hav, is there any other way around this?

Comment: @3GamersStudios Not to my knowledge, at least not in pure CSS. But search for common mono fonts, maybe you'll find one that you'll like. for example `font-family: Courier;`